# Microsoft Graph issue - Filtering output

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm exporting both custom and standard attributes of all users in Azure AD. I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around customizing the output when exporting.

For example, I'm seeking to export all users that are members, not Guests, with the below attributes:

```
$URI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?`$select=displayName,userPrincipalName, mail, department, jobTitle, extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute14, extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute15, accountEnabled, signInActivity, UserType, id&`$expand=manager(`$select=displayName,userPrincipalName)&`$top=999"
```

I've tried adding to the URI above to include `$filter=userType eq 'Guest'`

I've tried adjusting my report object to

```
$ReportLine  = [PSCustomObject] @{  
UserType           = $filter=$User.UserType -eq "Member"}
```

I've also tried modifying my write output code with no success:

```
Write-Host "All done. " $Report.Count "accounts processed - output available in c:\Temp\ReportUserSignin.csv."
$Report | Sort DisplayName | Out-GridView
$Report | ?{$_.UserType -eq "Guest"}| Sort {$_.LastSignIn -as [DateTime]} -Descending | Format-Table DisplayName, LastSignIn, Email | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation c:\Temp\ReportUserSignin.csv
```

The above two only results in True/False results of the user is a member or guest.

Can someone provide some insight as to what I'm missing here or even where the filter should be for the exported report? I greatly appreciate any and all advice! :)

Comment: How do you call Graph API? Could you share more code? Please share the whole URI with $filter query parameter.

Comment: @user2250152 Sure! $URI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=userType eq 'Guest'&$select=displayName,userPrincipalName, mail, department, jobTitle, extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute14, extension_1fe7973b28e74213b897d62528e614c7_extensionAttribute15, accountEnabled, signInActivity, UserType, id&`$expand=manager(`$select=displayName,userPrincipalName)&`$top=999"
I call / connect to graph by app authentication (successfully). Let me know if you need more code!